# Is it possible to have more than P2P on iPhone with Bluetooth

Tags: iphone, network-programming, bluetooth, gamekit

This seems like a straightforward google search answer, but after a while, I still can't be 100% sure of this. I've found Z2Live (http://www.z2live.com/), which is basically a layer above GameKit and they too use only P2P with Bluetooth. So I just want to be sure if I can only have P2P with Bluetooth or if I can have like 4 iPhones all connected to a server (who will also be a client) using Bluetooth. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone p2p - Is there a way to connect to more than 1 devices?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084066/iphone-p2p-is-there-a-way-to-connect-to-more-than-1-devices)

Answer (score 1):

I've been searching for this also and I can't find anything regarding to this problem. I've read somehere that you can only have 2 iPhones connected at the same time via bluetooth and for more you need to use Wi-Fi but apple's documentation says that you can connect multiple iPhones via Bluetooth although they lack information on this matter.

Can someone enlight us on this problem? It seems like is a very common one

Answer (score 0):

I'm also working on this problem presently, and my current belief is that it's not possible to do a multiple connection using the PeerPicker. Today I'm going to try and rig up a customised solution instead.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, GameKit uses the PANU profile (identified as 0x1115). If there is no GP or NAP service used by PANU device - that is, two PANU devices are talking directly - then only two devices can communicate.

So I presume that as long as you use Bluetooth for GameKit, you can only establish connection between a maximum of two users.