# iPhone P2P - is GKSession unreliable beyond 4 peers?

Tags: ios, networking, p2p

**Original question:**
The iOS Developer Library [mentions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameKitConcepts/GameKitConcepts.html) in the Game Kit Programming Guide  that

> The maximum size of a client-server game is 16 players.

Does this limitation also apply to P2P GKsessions?

This was already kind-of asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084066/iphone-p2p-is-there-a-way-to-connect-to-more-than-1-devices) (but from a different angle).

**Updated question:**Is GKSession reliable when more than 4 peers are connected?

*note:*The question was updated based on the [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13014131/766570) by [saulobrito](https://stackoverflow.com/users/715451/saulobrito) below.

**Reference:** One example of an app that uses a large group of peers connected is [Seedio](http://seedio-app.com/). You will notie that they are *not* using GKSession as bluetooth is not an option for connectivity (with GKSession, you can't even chose bluetooth or wi-fi.. GKSession does that for you.) Check out their [FAQ](http://seedio-app.com/support.htm) for some interesting information about why they chose Wi-fi rather than bluetooth.

Comment: Bump.  The documentation is unclear if the limit of 16 applies to the client-server version, or to that AND the peer-to-peer version.  Is peer-to-peer just two client-server schemes put together, or is the peer-to-peer version excepted from the limitation?

Comment: I would like to know the answer to that my self too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I can assure you is that GKSession is very unstable and you should not trust these docs. In fact, Apple recently decided to remove the documentation altogether.

I did a lot of testing and I would suggest that the practical limit is 4 connected devices (one acting as a server and 3 clients). Of course it's better that you do your own testing scenario.

I also couldn't find any game that allows more than 4 players. The only that I knew was Apple own Texas Hold'em - which allowed 8 players, but they decided to remove it.

And last, but not least, Game Center [imposes a 4 player limit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/MatchmakingwithGameCenter/MatchmakingwithGameCenter.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH12-SW2) to peer-to-peer games.

Yes I'm developing a game that should support 10 players but, in our tests, it became unstable/unusable when there were more than 4 devices. By unstable I mean: sometimes you can't find a peer and connection drops in less than a minute. To make matters worse, updating to iOS 6 brought some strange behaviors like freezing (no error, no stack trace, no nothing) while trying to send a message. Other odd thing: when a player loses connection, all other players get disconnected.

**EDIT:** did a lot of testing since that response and have more information to share:

**Using iOS 6 I was able to play reliably with 9 devices using either wi-fi or bluetooth**. There's stil a huge issue although: You can't connect devices using iOS 6 with devices using iOS 5 cause you will face unexplainable freezing-with-no-stack-trace time to time if any of the devices is with its wi-fi enabled. You either set iOS 6 as the minimum supported version for your App or you will have to ask users to disable their wi-fi and use bluetooth.

Comment: very interesting.. i'm kind of reaching the same conclusion myself.. So can you say that using bonjour would give more reliable results? and can you tell me a little more about your testing? are you testing a game in real time? and when you say unreliable.. is it in the form of connecting a device to another or too many dropped packets or losing connection half way etc?

Comment: I'm not an expert but I'd suggest that yes. You can use DNS-SD for advertise/discovery and build a socket server to keep the conversation going on. Isn't straightforward as GKSession but it's probably a safer bet. Here's a good answer about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844189/bonjour-over-bluetooth-without-gamekit.

Comment: Thanks for your important findings.. i'll actually change the title and question to reflect your answer, as your findings are more important than what i was asking for.. +1

Answer (score 3):

On iOS 6.0 I can confirm that GKSession allows at least 6 players.  I have found that you must make sure not to send messages to a peer until the state changes to connected though.

Overall, I think GKSession is a wonderful and simple API.  It will use bluetooth or WiFi, meaning that you don't even have to think about whether the phone is connected to a WiFi network.  The latency is nice and low ( I measured it at 4ms for unreliable and around 10ms for reliable networking ).

My main caveats are:

1. Use unreliable messaging if you can.
2. Make sure you set .available to NO on application exit ( if you're terminated while advertising, you may leave phantom sessions open ).
3. Do not try and send messages to a peer until the peer in question changes to the connected state.
4. Don't try to re-use a gksession once you've been disconnected.
5. You may need to retry a connection attempt ( I automatically retry 3 times if a connection attempt fails ).  My timeout is 10 seconds.
6. Throttle your reliable messaging.  I haven't quite figured out what the limit is, but eventually it seems like you will blow a transmission buffer and then your latency will balloon.  Again, this just isn't a problem when you use unreliable messaging.